# Deserializing JSON wrapper object with list returns null properties

Tags: java, json, jackson

I got json like below:

```
{"examinationTypes":[{"ExaminationTypeVO":{"id":1,"name":"Badanie krwi"}},{"ExaminationTypeVO":{"id":2,"name":"Spirometria"}},{"ExaminationTypeVO":{"id":3,"name":"Wymaz"}},{"ExaminationTypeVO":{"id":4,"name":"Ciśnienie"}},{"ExaminationTypeVO":{"id":5,"name":"EKG"}},{"ExaminationTypeVO":{"id":6,"name":"Elektrowstrząsy"}},{"ExaminationTypeVO":{"id":7,"name":"Tomografia"}},{"ExaminationTypeVO":{"id":8,"name":"Lewatywa"}},{"ExaminationTypeVO":{"id":9,"name":"Aneskopia"}},{"ExaminationTypeVO":{"id":10,"name":"Rektoskopia"}},{"ExaminationTypeVO":{"id":11,"name":"Kolonoskopioa"}},{"ExaminationTypeVO":{"id":12,"name":"Echo serca"}},{"ExaminationTypeVO":{"id":13,"name":"Ablacja"}},{"ExaminationTypeVO":{"id":14,"name":"Badnaie dopplerowskie"}},{"ExaminationTypeVO":{"id":15,"name":"Kapilaroskopia"}}]}
```

I have defined types:

```
@JsonRootName(value="ExaminationTypeVO")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ExaminationTypeVO {


private Long id;

private String name;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

and

```
public class ExaminationTypesVO {

private List<ExaminationTypeVO> examinationTypes;

public List<ExaminationTypeVO> getExaminationTypes() {
    return examinationTypes;
}

public void setExaminationTypes(List<ExaminationTypeVO> examinationTypes) {
    this.examinationTypes = examinationTypes;
}
```

When I am deserializing it like that:

`ExaminationTypesVO l = m.readValue(result, ExaminationTypesVO.class);`

I receive an wrapper object but the list inside contains objects of type ExaminationTypeVO with all properties set to null.

Can anybody help to figure it out?

Comment: I don't think `JsonRootName` works with nested objects. Start by investigating that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you have an extra level of object that you are trying to deserialize. Trying to not be confusing as I explain this: you have an array of objects, those objects contain a single `ExaminationTypeVO` object.

If you are stuck with the structure of the JSON that you provided, then you will need to add another "level" to your deserialization.  You can do this via a wrapper object inside of your `ExaminationTypesVO` class:

```
public class ExaminationTypesVO {
    private List<ExaminationTypeVOWrapper> examinationTypes;

    public List<ExaminationTypeVOWrapper> getExaminationTypes() {
        return examinationTypes;
    }

    public void setExaminationTypes(List<ExaminationTypeVOWrapper> examinationTypes) {
        this.examinationTypes = examinationTypes;
    }

    public static class ExaminationTypeVOWrapper {
        private final ExaminationTypeVO examinationTypeVO;

        @JsonCreator
        public ExaminationTypeVOWrapper(@JsonProperty("ExaminationTypeVO") ExaminationTypeVO examinationTypeVO) {
            this.examinationTypeVO = examinationTypeVO;
        }

        public ExaminationTypeVO getExaminationTypeVO() {
            return examinationTypeVO;
        }
    }
}
```

If you have control over the JSON that you are deserializing, you can just remove the extra "level" (`ExaminationTypeVO` wrapping object) and not have to change your code.  Your new JSON in this approach would look like:

```
{
    "examinationTypes": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Badanie krwi"
        }, ...
    ]
}
```

With either of these approaches you can remove both of the class-level annotations you have on `ExaminationTypeVO`.